# Copying file from remote server to my ubuntu desktop

Tags: remote-access, scp, ubuntu-10.10

I have confused how to do that. someone tell me to use `scp` but it still unclear for me.
I just can control the server using `ssh`.

I did like:

```
qa-desktop2@qa-desktop2:~$ scp jeinqa@136.198.117.4:/www/oqc/inspection_report.php qa-desktop2@10.230.35.212:/home/qa-desktop2/desktop
```

then type the password:

```
jeinqa@136.198.117.4's password:
```

then show:

```
Could not create directory '/home/jeinqa/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

why? what is the correct steps to to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qa-desktop2@qa-desktop2:~$ scp jeinqa@136.198.117.4:/www/oqc/inspection_report.php  /home/qa-desktop2/desktop
```

should be enough, assuming that `10.230.35.212` is your local machine that you run this on, so you omit the `user@host:` part for the local part of the copy action.

Comment: whether I just can copy a single file? how if I want to copy all file in directory?

Comment: Use `scp -r`. And read `man scp`.

Comment: and bear in mind its `scp -r <rest of command>` and not `scp <rest of command> -r`. Gommon gotcha

Answer (score 0):

Also, please read some info about `rsync` it is very powerful and has proven to be more powerful and useful then scp in most cases.

Also, you could try `sftp`, works like regular ftp but does it over the secure ssh connection.

Comment: rsync is a bit overkill for this, you do not need deltas etc. Also scp & sftp work on most SSH-enabled systems while rsync requires a special daemon